# If I am regularly working with propriatery software/hardware is it ok to liberally use the `Answer Your Own Question` checkbox

Tags: discussion

I work in the call centre industry and quite often find myself working with proprietary software/hardware that isn't well documented, either from the manufacturers or online.

In my downtime I would like to write about this work, both to help others who need to work with the same hardware/software in the future and also to understand things better myself.

I was thinking of starting a blog but then noticed the `Answer your own question` checkbox and my question is - Is it OK to liberally use this feature any time I find myself in what I would consider to be a unique situation?

I think that this would help other people who find themselves in the same situation in the future and also myself as I am sure that I would get a lot of constructive criticism regarding how I went about solving various problems from the community.

Would using the feature in this way be considered abusive or would it be accepted?

Comment: You have no idea how much I wish people had done this with Epicor's software...all ERA software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes!

The goal of StackExchange is to share everybody's information. If you have some information than share it with everybody else!

I've already made use of this feature posting two questions and solutions to them.

1. [How do I install a crx file on Google Chrome Dev?](https://superuser.com/questions/431977/how-do-i-install-a-crx-file-on-google-chrome-dev)
2. [Why is Google Chrome not starting after replacing udev with systemd-tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/431606/why-is-google-chrome-not-starting-after-replacing-udev-with-systemd-tools)

Answer (score 3):

I feel that it would be absolutely fine to do.  As outlined in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), it's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to a question you ask yourself.

There's a few gems in that blog posting (which are attributed to Jeff Atwood), but the main takeway that I'm getting from it, with respect to your question, is that this sort of thing is **perfectly acceptable.**